# convergences in $\mathcal {S'}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

**strong text**Let $\phi$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on $\mathbb R^{n}$ with

$ \operatorname{supp} \phi \subset \{\xi \in \mathbb R^{n}: |\xi|\leq 2, \phi(\xi)=1$ if $|\xi|\leq 1.$

> **My Question is**: How to show  $2^{jn}\hat{\phi}(2^{j}x)\to \delta$ in $\mathcal{S'}(\mathbb R^{n})$(= the space of tempered distributions) as $j\to \infty$  where $\delta$ stands for the $\delta-$distribution ?

(A  $\delta-$ distribution is , defined by
    $\left\langle \delta, \varphi \right\rangle = \varphi(0),$
meaning that $\delta$ evaluates a test function at 0.)

**Edit**: My attempt (after looking the following hint by RE): For $f\in \mathcal{S},$ it is suffice to prove: $|\int_{\mathbb R} [(2^{in} \hat{\phi}(2^{j}x)f(x)-\hat{f}(x)]dx|$ tends to 0 as $j\to \infty.$ Now I guess, we need to use kind of approximate identity but I don't know how ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The standard way to prove a limit in ${\mathcal S}'$ is to see how these
distributions act on a member of $\mathcal S$.  If $f \in \mathcal S$, 
you want
$$ \int 2^{jn} \hat{\phi}(2^j x) f(x)\; dx \to f(0)$$
First step: express the integral on the left in terms of $\phi$ and the inverse Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: Prof. RE thanks; I have tried(see edit above) as you have suggested, but please can you tell me am I trying in the right direction ? Thanks a lot;